# C# datagridview set databound column value to a chosen default one

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView bound to a list of custom objects. A column is bound to a double datatype, and when I try to empty its content (to null), it throws a data error indicating DbNull cannot be converted into Double. What I'd like to accomplish is when a user enters a null value for the databound column, I'd like to set it to a default generic value, say 3.0.

I can handle dataerror and replace the value there, but this seems like a hackish solution. What is the recommended way of handling this?

Edit:

Here's my data class. The double datatype mentioned above is USL.

```
public class SPCModelDTO
{
        public string ProcessName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string ModelName { get; set; }
        public double USL { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my code for databinding

```
dgvModel.DataSource = new BindingList<SPCModelDTO>(modelList);
```

Matching property name is declared in designer w/ respect to the dataclass properties.

As a side note, **I cannot change USL's datatype to a nullable double**.

Comment: Can you show the class where your property with `DataType` `Double` is declared.

Comment: @CurseStacker See edit

Answer (score 0):

Create a ViewModel which will be bound to the `DataGrdiView`.
In the ViewModel you can wrap `USL` in the nullable type

```
public class SPCModelDTOViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SPCModelDTO _Model;
    public double? USL 
    { 
        get { return _Model.USL;} 
        set 
        {
            if(value.HasValue == false)
                _Model.USL = 3.0;
            else
                _Model.USL = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChangedEvent();
        } 
    }
    //Other model's properties
}
```

Line `this.RaisePropertyChangedEvent();` will notify View(DataGridView) about changes and empty(null) value will be changed to default one
Of course your ViewModel class must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`
[How to: Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: I've considered this, but having to create a nearly identical class just for this purpose seemed overkill for me. Does winforms datagridview offer no functionality for replacing null value with something else?

Comment: I don't think this is overkill if you want keep Form's(View) code separated from Business/Data code and especially in your case when types of the model isn't compatible with UI controls. If you don't care about this then use `DataError` eventhandler which is same eventhandler as others  - I don't see using eventhandlers of control as "hackish" in your particular case

Answer (score 0):

for a databound column you can set `DataSourceNullValue` in `DatagridViewColumn.DefaultCellStyle`

```
dgvModel.DataSource = data;
var col = dgvModel.Columns["USL"];
col.DefaultCellStyle.DataSourceNullValue = 3;
```

Comment: This was actually my first port of call, and I've already tried this but strangely, it gives me the same error